# How to send image from Angular to Node JS using express and multer?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multer

I search for hours in google to find a solution but nothing worked on my project. I want a module that can send image from Angular and store them in a directory of Node JS.

I know there is something wrong because req.file is always undefined...

Here is my Node JS code :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const upload = multer({
    dest: 'assets/' // this saves your file into a directory called "uploads"
  });

app.use(express.static('assets'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

  app.route(requestPath).post((req, res) => {
    upload.single('image')
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

My Angular Service :

```
  addImage( ... , fd){ 
    return this.http.post(requestPath, {
  file: fd 
})
```

}

My angular code :

```
selectedFile = null;

imageSelected(event){
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  }

onSubmit(){
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.imageService.addImage( ... , fd).subscribe( _ => {
        this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
      });
    }
```

My HTML code :

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" [formGroup]="addImage" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Choisissez la photo</label>
          <input type="file" id="image" name="image" class="form-control" formControlName="photo" (change)="imageSelected($event)" required>
        </div>
```

Thank you so much if some one can help me ! 
I'm making a photo gallery, but it's kind of useless if i can't upload photo on it...

Answer (score 1):

Try (in Node) logging req.**body**.file:

```
  app.route(requestPath).post((req, res) => {
    upload.single('image')
    console.log(req.body.file);
```

Also, in the Angular service, after you define the FormData variable, logout your file and file.name variables to the console to make sure you have data there to send in the service. This will tell you if the problem is in the front end, or the Node side.

```
const fd = new FormData();

console.log("this.selectedFile",this.selectedFile;
console.log("this.selectedFile.name", this.selectedFile.name);

fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 
the log of req.body.file is {}

And the log in the front seems good, the first one show the file with the content, and the second one the right name. I don't really understand where does the problem come from...